# Cloud Functions calling another Cloud Functions faces "Access is forbidden"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call a Cloud Function from another one and for that, I'm following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function).

I've created two functions. This is the code for the function that calls the other one:

```js
const {get} = require('axios');

// TODO(developer): set these values
const REGION = 'us-central1';
const PROJECT_ID = 'my-project-######';
const RECEIVING_FUNCTION = 'hello-world';

// Constants for setting up metadata server request
// See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity#request_signature
const functionURL = `https://${REGION}-${PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/${RECEIVING_FUNCTION}`;
const metadataServerURL =
  'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=';
const tokenUrl = metadataServerURL + functionURL;

exports.proxy = async (req, res) => {
  // Fetch the token
  const tokenResponse = await get(tokenUrl, {
    headers: {
      'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google',
    },
  });
  const token = tokenResponse.data;
  console.log(`Token: ${token}`);

  // Provide the token in the request to the receiving function
  try {
    console.log(`Calling: ${functionURL}`);
    const functionResponse = await get(functionURL, {
      headers: {Authorization: `bearer ${token}`},
    });
    res.status(200).send(functionResponse.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
    res.status(500).send('An error occurred! See logs for more details.');
  }
};
```

It's almost identical to the one proposed in the documentation. I just added a couple of logs and I'm stringifying the error before logging it. Following the instructions on that page, I've also added to my `hello-world` function the permission for the `my-project-######@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` service account to have the `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker` role:

```
$ gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding hello-world \
>   --member='serviceAccount:my-project-######@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' \
>   --role='roles/cloudfunctions.invoker'
bindings:
- members:
  - allUsers
  - serviceAccount:my-project--######@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudfunctions.invoker
etag: ############
version: 1
```

But still, when I call the code above, I get `403 Access is forbidden`. I'm sure this is returned by the `hello-world` function since I can see the logs from the code. I can see the token and I can see the correct URL for the `hello-world` function in the logs. Also, I can call the `hello-world` function directly from GCP console. Both of the functions are `Trigger type: HTTP` and only `hello-world` function is `Ingress settings: Allow internal traffic only`. The other one, `Ingress settings: Allow all traffic`.

Can someone please help me understand what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If your `Hello world` function is in [`Allow internal only` mode](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings) this mean:

> Only requests from VPC networks in the same project or VPC Service Controls perimeter are allowed. All other requests are rejected.

To reach the functions, you have to call it through your VPC. For this,

- [Create a serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) in the same region of your function (take care, serverless VPC connector is not available in all region!!)
- [Add it in your second function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc)
- [Route all the traffic to the serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#egress_settings) (I'm not sure that if you route only internal traffic that works)

Comment: I will give this a try, thanks. One question, though. Is there any way I can have a Cloud Function which is not public (I can call it from other functions but not from the Internet) but does not need a VPC?

Comment: No, it's not possible. In fact, when you expose a "private function" (I mean a function that requires IAM permission to be called) on internet, only the authorized request are routed to your function. The other requests (without authorization or with unauthorized token) are filtered by Google Front End and discarded. They never reach your function and you don't pay for these bad request (it's Google Front End, so Google "pays" it). Using IAM + internal callable function is very secure, in zero trust mode

Comment: Your answer makes me doubt if there's a misunderstanding here. I don't care for functions that are exposed. I just want a function as a microservice and I don't like the idea of having a VPC. I mean how come if I call a function indirectly (through a pub/sub), it does not need to be in a VPC but if I want to call it from my own function, then it needs to be in a VPC! That does not make sense to me. But I will try your suggestion the first chance I'll get. Thanks again.

Comment: If you use PubSub to call your function, that accept only internal ingress, you have to create a VPC SC (Service Control). No VPC this time, but not really easier to manage. If you don't care about VPC, simply use IAM role to control the access to your function!

Comment: I still need to master VPC and VPC SC, so there are definitely things that I don't know about them. But I have created a Cloud Function with trigger set to pub/sub without any VPC or VPC SC and I managed to call it by publishing a message to the topic. Also, when you say use IAM role to control the access, do you mean to set the function as ingress allow-all-traffic?

Comment: Yes. Don't allow unauthenticated users to your Cloud Functions and allow all traffic. Like this, all requests land on Google Front End (GFE). It checks if security token is present and valid. And only valid request are forwarded to the Cloud Functions. You are protected against DDoS and malicious attack like this. Only request with valid and authorized token (managed by IAM) can request your function